# MySQL 5.7: Query is faster with order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I'm doing some tests on MySQL 5.7 database, and I came across a situation that I can't understand:

When I make the following query:

```
select
    *
from
    employee
where
    (admission_date between '2020-01-01 23:59:59' and '2022-07-25 23:59:59')
    and registered = 0
    and payment = 1
order by
    name;
```

When I run without "order by name" the query runs in 6s, with "order by name" the query runs in 86ms.

NOTE:

There is no index for column "name".

The table uses Engine = InnoDB

I ran EXPLAIN, but since it's a simple query, it didn't bring up any significant information:

```
1 SIMPLE employee ALL 117432 0.01 Using where; Using filesort
```

I did the same test on the MySQL 8 database, and there was no difference with the "order by name", using the same database, with the same structure.

I'm trying to understand the situation, because I want to migrate to MySQL 8, and I would like to understand if there is any configuration or strategy that makes MySQL 5.7 have a difference with order by.

**CREATE TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
   `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
   `payment` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `registered` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `temp_file_1` blob,
   `temp_file_2` blob,
   `temp_file_3` blob,
   `temp_file_4` blob,
   `admission_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=123594854 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**STATISTIC INFO:**

```
Row Count: 144.183
Row format: Dynamic
Max data length: 0
Index length: 0
Data free: 3M
Data Length: 6,5G
Avg Row Length: 48.039
```

**EXPLAIN MYSQL 5.7 (WITH ORDER BY name):**

```
    {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "451751.79"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "160.19"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_name": "employee",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 144183,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 160,
        "filtered": "0.11",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "451559.56",
          "eval_cost": "32.04",
          "prefix_cost": "451591.60",
          "data_read_per_join": "25K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "name",
          "payment",
          "registered",
          "temp_file_1",
          "temp_file_2",
          "temp_file_3",
          "temp_file_4",
          "admission date"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`financer_db`.`employee`.`payment` = 1) and (`financer_db`.`employee`.`registered` = 0) and (`financer_db`.`employee`.`date_admission` between '2020-01-01 23:59:59' and '2022-07-25 23:59:59'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EXPLAIN MYSQL 5.7 (WITHOUT ORDER BY name):**

```
    {
   "query_block": {
     "select_id": 1,
     "cost_info": {
       "query_cost": "451591.60"
     },
     "table": {
       "table_name": "employee",
       "access_type": "ALL",
       "rows_examined_per_scan": 144183,
       "rows_produced_per_join": 160,
       "filtered": "0.11",
       "cost_info": {
         "read_cost": "451559.56",
         "eval_cost": "32.04",
         "prefix_cost": "451591.60",
         "data_read_per_join": "25K"
       },
       "used_columns": [
         "id",
         "name",
         "payment",
         "registered",
         "temp_file_1",
         "temp_file_2",
         "temp_file_3",
         "temp_file_4",
         "admission date"
       ],
       "attached_condition": "((`financer_db`.`employee`.`payment` = 1) and (`financer_db`.`employee`.`registered` = 0) and (`financer_db`.`employee`.`date_admission` between '2020-01-01 23:59:59' and '2022-07-25 23:59:59'))"
     }
   }
}
```

**EXPLAIN MYSQL 8.0.29 (WITH ORDER BY name):**

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "405586.71"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "134.84"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_name": "employee",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 121369,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 134,
        "filtered": "0.11",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "405438.39",
          "eval_cost": "13.48",
          "prefix_cost": "405451.87",
          "data_read_per_join": "21K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "name",
          "payment",
          "registered",
          "temp_file_1",
          "temp_file_2",
          "temp_file_3",
          "temp_file_4",
          "admission date"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`financer_db`.`employee`.`payment` = 1) and (`financer_db`.`employee`.`registered` = 0) and (`financer_db`.`employee`.`date_admission` between '2020-01-01 23:59:59' and '2022-07-25 23:59:59'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EXPLAIN MYSQL 8.0.29 (WITHOUT ORDER BY name):**

```
{
   "query_block": {
     "select_id": 1,
     "cost_info": {
       "query_cost": "405451.87"
     },
     "table": {
       "table_name": "employee",
       "access_type": "ALL",
       "rows_examined_per_scan": 121369,
       "rows_produced_per_join": 134,
       "filtered": "0.11",
       "cost_info": {
         "read_cost": "405438.39",
         "eval_cost": "13.48",
         "prefix_cost": "405451.87",
         "data_read_per_join": "21K"
       },
       "used_columns": [
         "id",
         "name",
         "payment",
         "registered",
         "temp_file_1",
         "temp_file_2",
         "temp_file_3",
         "temp_file_4",
         "admission date"
       ],
       "attached_condition": "((`financer_db`.`employee`.`payment` = 1) and (`financer_db`.`employee`.`registered` = 0) and (`financer_db`.`employee`.`date_admission` between '2020-01-01 23:59:59' and '2022-07-25 23:59:59'))"
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: You must provide complete CREATE TABLE for your table and EXPLAIN for both queries. Also provide statistic info (total and matched rows amount).

Comment: @Akina I have attached all the information.

Comment: The total amount of rows is visible. But how many rows matches the conditions (for each separate condition and for all 3 conditions applied together)? Now it is not clear... Does `registered` and `payment` columns are boolean by fact? PS. You may try to create an index which will improve the query (if this is possible), but its expression depends on detailed statistic mentioned above. PPS. Do you really need in all columns to be selected?

Comment: Did you run each timing twice?  The first run may have to fetch from disk; the second may not need the I/O.  Also, was the "row type" Dynamic in all cases?

Comment: @Akina As per CREATE TABLE, the fields are of type INT. I don't want to optimize, I want to understand the difference with and without order by. There are 3 conditions, according to SELECT.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I took that care, I always run at least 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think "lazy load" kicked in:

Clue:

```
Row Count: 144.183
Data Length: 6,5G
Avg Row Length: 48.039  <-- Lots of off-record data to fetch        
"rows_examined_per_scan": 121369,   <-- lots of rows in table
"rows_produced_per_join": 134,      <-- very few need sorting
```

Without lazy load, it would fetch all columns for all rows.

With lazy load, it did not need to fetch the blobs until it had decided which ones to deliver.

The `ORDER BY` tricked it into doing all the `WHERE` stuff before fetching all (`*`).

It seems like it could (should!) use lazy load for both cases.  Submit a bug report: bugs.mysql.com

This should make *both* SELECTs on *both* MySQL versions run even faster:

```
INDEX(registered, payment, admission_date)
```

(The column involved in the 'range' test must come after the columns bested with '='.)

**Lazy loading**

This is a relatively new optimization in MySQL/MariaDB.  I do not know how to control it.  But there is a workaround -- do it yourself:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM tbl ... ) AS a
    JOIN tbl AS b  ON (b.id = a.id)
```

This way the "derived table" (the subquery) fetches only the ids and can use indexes efficiently.  Then the small number of resulting ids are used (efficiently, via the `PRIMARY KEY`) to fetch the bulky blobs.

Note:  This assumes that the derived table selects only a fraction of the ids -- via WHERE / GROUP BY / DISTINCT / LIMIT.

(My recommended INDEX is likely to have the same "lazy" effect.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can optimize, but first I want to understand the difference. I will submit it to bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: Is there any configuration for this?

Comment: @MarquesKarlx - Sorry; I have seen such; but don't remember the details.  (And it may not use the word "lazy".)

Comment: @MarquesKarlx - I added more.